# Accessing Canvas refs from another component in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas, vuejs3

I have a really simple project created with @vue3/cli project. My problem is really straight forward but I couldn't find a simple or any solution to that.

I have two components. One component has webcam video render in a video tag and another component has a html5 canvas. I want to render a part of the video on the canvas in the other component. I don't know how to send video image from one component to another component.

Both components are registered under one view at the same level of hierarchy.

```
Home -->
    WebCam.vue  
    Canvas.vue
```

Now I have tried sending the video as data from WebCam component to Canvas component using  -

```
this.emitter.emit('cam-image', {
                       id:'video'
                    image: this.video 
                })
```

I am using mitt for emitting events but this isn't working at all. I see the data received as entire video tag logged in my console.

```
this.emitter.on("cam-image", data => { 
                 console.log(data.image)
                    this.canvasContext.drawImage(
                      data.image,
                     0, 0,
                     300, 150,
                    0, 0, this.canvasWidth, this.canvasHeight
                );
            })
```

So I though if I could access the refs from Canvas component into WebCam component and render the image directly from there.

Comment: You can try using vuex for store and state management

Comment: @tuhin47 how can I use veux to do that?

Comment: @tuhin47 I got one answer but I feel that using provide and inject is a overkill for this simple usecase. Can you please tell me your solution? What I did basically, I stored the  this.$refs.webcam to webcam value in store and try to access that value in another component. It didn't work without any fail.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options to do so. If you only have a single instance, then a global variable might be the easiest way. You can do a global variable with Vuex or just using a global reactive instance (example with the later)

```js
# global.js
import { ref } from "vue";
export const canvasRef = ref(null);
```

you can then import the variable in your components

```html
<template>
  ...
  <canvas ref="canvasRef">
  ...
</template>

<script>
  import { canvasRef } = "global.js";

  export default {
    setup() {
      // expose to template
      return {
        canvasRef 
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

You can import it the same way in the other component, and the two components will be sharing the instance.

You can also use the global properies from the app context with `getCurrentInstance().appContext.config.globalProperties.$canvasRef` by setting that somewhere in the app to `ref(null)` (or when defining the vue app `app.config.globalProperties`)

The more *"proper"* way I'd say is to use the provide/inject. Proper, because it doesn't require a global instance so it makes it available only for the components that need it so allows multiple instances.

In Home.vue you would add the `provide` and in the children you would use the `inject` that would make it available. This is similar to the context api in react.

Here is an example, note that due to the restrictions of stackoverflow, the camera API is disabled, but you can see it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dapo/t4b7jf0m/2/) still.

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    Vue.provide('canvasRef', Vue.ref(null))
    return {}
  }
});

app.component("WebcamComponent", {
  template: `<div>Webcam<div id="webcam"></div><button @click="onClick"><button></div>`,
  setup() {
    Webcam.set({
      width: 320,
      height: 240,
      image_format: 'jpeg',
      jpeg_quality: 90
    });

    Vue.onMounted(() => {
      Webcam.attach('#webcam');
    })
    const canvasRef = Vue.inject('canvasRef');

    const onClick = () => {
      Webcam.snap(function(data_uri, canvas) {
        const ctx = canvasRef.value.getContext('2d')
        ctx.drawImage( canvas, 0, 0 );
      })
    };

    return {
      onClick
    };
  }
});

app.component("CanvasComponent", {
  template: `<div>Canvas<div><canvas ref="canvasRef"/></div></div>`,
  setup() {
    const canvasRef = Vue.inject('canvasRef');
    return {
      canvasRef
    };
  }
});

app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcamjs/1.0.26/webcam.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <webcam-component></webcam-component>
  <canvas-component></canvas-component>
</div>
```